#  Error while inserting record in database

Tags: java, spring, sybase

Sometime in production we face this problem , I have tried to search the cause of this but not yet good luck.

`com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: The parameter of type 61 did not have a valid value.`

When we run the query manually it works fine which gave below error.So i think query is fine.

```
        SQL state [ZZZZZ]; error code [3814]; The parameter of type 61 did not have a valid value.
    ; nested exception is com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: The parameter of type 61 did not have a valid value.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:811)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:833)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlUpdate.updateByNamedParam(SqlUpdate.java:248)
    at com.cachestore.sql.PTMSSqlUpdate.updateByNamedParam(PTMSSqlUpdate.java:35)
    at com.cachestore.PTMSCacheStore.store(PTMSCacheStore.java:277)
    ... 6 more
    Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: The parameter of type 61 did not have a valid value.
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.updateLoop(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:817)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:586)
    ... 11 more
```

Can you guys help me to find out what could be the possible reason for error `The parameter of type 61 did not have a valid value.` , The field is of `char(2)` type where i suspects.

It happens very rarely so we are not able to reproduce it.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Sybase error message.

> Explanation: Command failed due to invalid or illegal request. Check syntax, semantics, and permissions. Take any corrective action indicated by message.

Take a look at the [Documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.39996_1250/html/svrtsg/svrtsg317.htm)

Try to catch the Exception and print the param list with values in your catch statement, this will enable you to check the values when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have not shown us your code and your DB schema. But I think that exception is very clear. It says that 2 types: the java type and the DB type are not compatible.

As far as I understand you are trying to insert `char` or may be `char[]` into DB column of type `varchar` or something like that. Check this again. Probably you have to turn your char array into string before inserting it into DB.

Comment: In DB we have column of type char(2).

Answer (score 0):

Sybase type 61 is `TDS_DATETIME` (0x3D = 61 decimal). This types described in `TDS 5.0 Reference Pages` `Datatype Summary`.
It means that server does not likes value due to size, content or something wrong with parameters before that one in `TDS` packet.